# Error : No named parameter with the name 'videoId' youtube_player_iframe

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube-player-flutter

I have been facing this problem for over a month, and I haven't been able to find a solution so far. I have searched and used artificial intelligence tools like ChatGPT, Google Bard, and Github Copilot, but none of them could provide the appropriate solution.

When building my project with "flutter run," I encountered several issues due to the use of "youtube_player_iframe."

I have solved most of the problems, but there is one issue that I haven't been able to resolve yet. The error is as follows:

```dart
lib/screens/items/youtube_videos.dart:28:13: Error: No named parameter with the name 'videoId'.
            videoId:
            ^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Sheko/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/youtube_player_iframe-4.0.4/lib/src/controller/youtube_player_controller.dart:27:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  YoutubePlayerController({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
```

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

Version:

- Flutter: 3.18.0-0.2.pre • channel beta
- Dart: 3.3.0-174.3.beta
- youtube_player_iframe: 5.0.0

Here is the "youtube_videos.dart" file where the problems appear.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_iframe/youtube_player_iframe.dart';
import 'package:be_app_mobile/models/side_item.dart';
import 'package:be_app_mobile/models/general.dart';
import 'package:be_app_mobile/helpers/font_helper.dart';

class YouTubeVideos extends StatefulWidget {
  const YouTubeVideos({Key? key, required this.item, required this.general})
      : super(key: key);

  final SideItem item;
  final General general;

  @override
  State<YouTubeVideos> createState() => _YouTubeVideosState();
}

class _YouTubeVideosState extends State<YouTubeVideos> {
  double size = 0.0;
  late List<YoutubePlayerController> _controllers;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controllers = widget.item.youtubeVideos
        .map<YoutubePlayerController>(
          (video) => YoutubePlayerController(
            videoId:
                YoutubePlayerController.convertUrlToId(video.videoUrl) ?? '',
            params: YoutubePlayerParams(
              showControls: !video.hideControls,
              showFullscreenButton: true,
              loop: video.isLive,
            ),
          ),
        )
        .toList();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (var controller in _controllers) {
      controller.close();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: widget.general.getApplicationColor(),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  YoutubePlayer(
                    controller: _controllers[index],
                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                  ),
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        height: 80,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          widget.item.youtubeVideos[index].videoTitle,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          maxLines: 2,
                          style: getFontStyle(16, Colors.white,
                              FontWeight.normal, widget.general),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
            itemCount: _controllers.length,
            separatorBuilder: (context, _) {
              return SizedBox(height: size);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have been facing this problem for over a month, and I haven't been able to find a solution so far. I have searched and used artificial intelligence tools like ChatGPT, Google Bard, and Github Copilot, but none of them could provide the appropriate solution.

When building my project with "flutter run," I encountered several issues due to the use of "youtube_player_iframe."

I have solved most of the problems, but there is one issue that I haven't been able to resolve yet. The error is as follows:

```dart
lib/screens/items/youtube_videos.dart:28:13: Error: No named parameter with the name 'videoId'.
            videoId:
            ^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Sheko/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/youtube_player_iframe-4.0.4/lib/src/controller/youtube_player_controller.dart:27:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  YoutubePlayerController({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
```

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter), you can see that the YoutubeVideoController has a named constructor called **fromVideoId**:

```
final _controller = YoutubePlayerController.fromVideoId(
                      videoId: '<video-id>',
                      autoPlay: false,
                      params: const 
                 YoutubePlayerParams(showFullscreenButton: true),
   );
```

Therefore, you need to use that as there is no such named constructor as YoutubePlayerController.

This can be also evidenced [inside the project itself](https://github.com/sarbagyastha/youtube_player_flutter/blob/master/packages/youtube_player_iframe/lib/src/controller/youtube_player_controller.dart):

```
 factory YoutubePlayerController.fromVideoId({
    required String videoId,
    YoutubePlayerParams params = const YoutubePlayerParams(),
    bool autoPlay = false,
    double? startSeconds,
    double? endSeconds,
})
```

Comment: The problem is specifically with the youtube_player_iframe package and not youtube_player_flutter

Comment: @Sheko - The tag in question states youtube-player-flutter.

Comment: I can't create new tag for " youtube-player-iframe" because I am a new member
So I added a tag similar to it to find someone who can help me

Comment: Hi, @tomerpacific
Thank you very much for helping me
Could you please help me where exactly to put this code or what code should I replace in its place?
Because I am not a Flutter programmer and I am not an expert

Comment: @Sheko - Just replace the code you have creating a YoutubeController with what I have shown in the answer. If my answer helped, please mark it as such.